# How do I animate adding an item to a Silverlight Toolkit WrapPanel

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, wrappanel

I'm building eyecandy to a WP7 application.

I have a WrapPanel and I'm adding items to it in code. 
Instead of just popping up, I'd like these items to slide in to the WrapPanel one by one. 
How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

One really simple method you can use to snazz things up a bit that I would recommend is [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff979339%28v=expression.40%29.aspx), well worth looking into for your needs as it accomplishes exactly what you're looking for quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that animates the element and play that storyboard when you add items.

Blend is a good tool to create your storyboards. Here is a tutorial on [how to create a storyboard with Blend](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-and-using-storyboards-in-blendsilverlight-part-i/).

Comment: That only really answers the question "how is animation done in wp7 in general". In any case, it seems animating individual images doesn't work within wrappanel, anyway.